# Java Canvas or JPanel

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, java-canvas

When making a graphics canvas in Java, which would be better to extend? Should you extend JPanel or Canvas? Are there any performance considerations?

Comment: Found my answer: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JPanel.html

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to position other components within the custom rendered area, sub-classing a `JComponent` is often all that is necessary (`JPanel` provides nothing more that is especially useful).

---

### Mixing Swing with AWT

BTW - be especially wary of mixing Swing with AWT.  It generally causes rendering problems for Swing floating GUI elements.  Java 7 promises to provide functionality to seamlessly mix Swing and AWT based components.

#### E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MixSwingAwt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));

        String[] fruit = {"Apples", "Oranges", "Pears"};
        JComboBox fruitChoice = new JComboBox(fruit);
        p.add(fruitChoice, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        p.add(new TextArea(10,20));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
    }
}
```

#### Screenshot

Screenshot of the dialog using Java 6, when the `JComboBox` is expanded.
[image]

We can see the top of `Apples`, but the rest of the list is missing.